# Basic Stack Operations using Linked List in C

Tags: c, linked-list, stack

I have made a few functions for some basic stack operations using linked lists. Please review my code and suggest some ways to increase its readability. I would also love to hear ideas on how to make my code more compact and simple.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

void Traversal(struct node *ptr)
{
    do
    {
        printf("The element is : %d\n", ptr->data);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    } while (ptr->next != NULL);
}

int isEmpty(struct node *top)
{
    if (top == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int isFull(struct node *top)
{
    struct node *n = malloc(sizeof(struct node *));
    if (n == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
    free(n);
}

struct node *push(struct node *top, int x)
{
    if (isFull(top))
    {
        printf("Stack Overflow\n");
    }
    else
    {
        struct node *n = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        n->data = x;
        n->next = top;
        top = n;
    }
    return top;
}

struct node *pop(struct node *top)
{
    if (isEmpty(top))
    {
        printf("Stack Underflow\n");
    }
    else
    {
        struct node *n = top;
        top = top->next;
        free(n);
    }
    return top;
}

struct node *peek(struct node *top, int atPosition)  // To view the value stored at a specific postion
{
    struct node *ptr = top;
    if (atPosition < 0)
    {
        printf("Invalid Index\n");
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < atPosition && ptr->next != NULL; i++)
        {
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        printf("The data at index %d is %d\n", atPosition, ptr->data);
    }
    free(ptr);
    return top;
}

struct node *stackTop(struct node *top)
{
    printf("The data stored in stack top is %d\n", top->data);
    return top;
}

struct node *stackBottom(struct node *top)
{
    struct node *ptr = top;
    while (ptr->next != NULL)
    {
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    printf("The data stored in stack bottom is %d\n", ptr->data);
    free(ptr);
    return top;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`push()` has undefined behaviour any time its `malloc()` returns a null pointer.

`isFull()` leaks memory (because the matching `free()` call is unreachable).  Also, whether or not an allocation is successful tells us nothing about *future* allocations.

Instead of the broken and unreliable `isFull()`, work on the principle of attempting the action and taking appropriate recovery steps when it fails (sometimes described as *easier to ask for forgiveness than permission*, or EAFP):

```
struct node *push(struct node *top, int x)
{
    struct node *n = malloc(sizeof *n);
    if (!n) { return n; }  /* failure */
    n->data = x;
    n->next = top;
    top = n;
    return top;
}
```

It's usually a bad idea for low-level library functions to generate output (especially to `stdout`) - you might want to use the code in a GUI program, and report errors via a status bar or pop-up window, for example.  I would make it the caller's responsibility to examine the result and report it appropriately:

```
if (!push(top, x) {
    fputs("Out of memory\n", stderr); /* Not "stack overflow" - that's misleading! */
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on how to write a more reliable ```isFull()``` function applying the EAFP principle

Comment: As I demonstrate, `isFull()` isn't necessary.  Instead, where it's used (e.g. in `push()`, attempt the allocation, and take alternative action if it fails.  There's _no_ reliable way to know in advance whether allocation will succeed.  "Container is full" is only meaningful for a container with a predetermined capacity.

Answer (score 2):

- `isEmpty` is anti-idiomatic:

  ```
    if (top == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
  ```

  is a very long way to say

  ```
    return top == NULL;
  ```
- `isFull` is very dubious. Why call `malloc` twice? `push` is very well capable to detect the `malloc` failure.

  BTW, once `malloc` fails, it is unsafe to call `printf`.
- The utility library shall not print anything. Returning a success/failure indication is enough; let the caller take an appropriate recovery action.

  In any case, error messages shall go to `stderr`, not `stdout`.
- Why `peek` frees the `ptr`? Consider what happens on `atPosition` being 1. You have stack corruption, and a memory leak right away.

  Also, if `atPosition` is larger than the stack size, `peek` reports incorrect results (there is no such position, yet it prints something).
- `stackBottom` should test that the stack is not empty. Otherwise, `ptr->next` dereferences a null pointer.

  And again, it should not `free` anything.

Comment: In `peek` and `stackBottom` , I used `free()` because the main utility of these functions was only to print the required values to the user. Is there any specific reason why I should not use `free()` in these functions?

Comment: Why do you say it's unsafe to call `printf()` after a `malloc()` failure?  That seems reasonable to me.